# Desktop Dimmer won't run on my Ubuntu 20.04 because of Harfbuzz being too old

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I am trying to install [Desktop Dimmer v4.0.4 (amd64)](https://github.com/sidneys/desktop-dimmer/releases/tag/v4.0.4) on my Ubuntu 20.04 using the DEB package. The app shows up in the Applications menu but does not open. Upon trying to run it as a command-line utility I get the following error:

```
user@thehost:~$ desktop-dimmer 
Gtk-Message: 18:23:15.355: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

(desktop-dimmer:2454): Pango-ERROR **: 18:23:15.610: Harfbuzz version too old (1.2.7)

Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

How do I update Harfbuzz on my Ubuntu?

**Update #1:**

```
user@thehost:~/Downloads$ ldd $(which desktop-dimmer)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff3ede6000)
    libnode.so => not found
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f3688ebe000)
    libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f3688a64000)
    libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f36889a9000)
    libatk-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f368897f000)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f368879e000)
    libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f368878a000)
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f3688762000)
    libcairo.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f368863f000)
    libpango-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f36885f0000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f3688531000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f36884ea000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f3688488000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f3688437000)
    libXi.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f3688425000)
    libXcursor.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f3688418000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f3688413000)
    libXrandr.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f3688406000)
    libXcomposite.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007f36883ff000)
    libXext.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f36883ea000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f36883e2000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f36881d8000)
    libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f368809b000)
    libXtst.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6 (0x00007f3687e95000)
    libXss.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXss.so.1 (0x00007f3687e8e000)
    libgconf-2.so.4 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgconf-2.so.4 (0x00007f3687e5b000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f3687e55000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f3687e4a000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f3687d21000)
    libnss3.so => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss3.so (0x00007f3687bd2000)
    libnssutil3.so => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnssutil3.so (0x00007f3687b9d000)
    libsmime3.so => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmime3.so (0x00007f3687b6d000)
    libnspr4.so => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnspr4.so (0x00007f3687b2d000)
    libffmpeg.so => not found
    libasound.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2 (0x00007f3687a36000)
    libcups.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcups.so.2 (0x00007f368799b000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f3687993000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f3687965000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f3687784000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3687635000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f368761a000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3687428000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3688ef7000)
    libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f368740d000)
    libXinerama.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007f3687408000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f36873ec000)
    libmount.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 (0x00007f368738c000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f3687361000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f3687343000)
    libpixman-1.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007f368729c000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f3687264000)
    libxcb-shm.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f368725f000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f3687235000)
    libxcb-render.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f3687224000)
    libfribidi.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfribidi.so.0 (0x00007f3687207000)
    libthai.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0x00007f36871fc000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f36870f7000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f36870ee000)
    libffi.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7 (0x00007f36870e0000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f3687033000)
    libdbus-glib-1.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-glib-1.so.2 (0x00007f3687008000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f3686f95000)
    libplc4.so => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplc4.so (0x00007f3686f8e000)
    libplds4.so => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplds4.so (0x00007f3686f87000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f3686f3a000)
    libavahi-common.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavahi-common.so.3 (0x00007f3686f2c000)
    libavahi-client.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavahi-client.so.3 (0x00007f3686f19000)
    libgnutls.so.30 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007f3686d43000)
    libblkid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007f3686cea000)
    libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007f3686c5a000)
    libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f3686c54000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f3686c4c000)
    libdatrie.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007f3686c42000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f3686c13000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f3686bec000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f3686bcb000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f3686aad000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f36869d0000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f368699d000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f3686996000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f3686987000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f3686851000)
    libidn2.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007f3686830000)
    libunistring.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007f36866ae000)
    libtasn1.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007f3686696000)
    libnettle.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.7 (0x00007f368665c000)
    libhogweed.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.5 (0x00007f3686624000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f36865a0000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f3686586000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f3686561000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f368655a000)
```

**Update #2**

```
user@thehost:~/Downloads$ apt policy libharfbuzz0b
libharfbuzz0b:
  Installed: 2.6.4-1ubuntu4
  Candidate: 2.6.4-1ubuntu4
  Version table:
 *** 2.6.4-1ubuntu4 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: @StephenKitt Updated again. Also `lscpu` says `Architecture: x86_64` so I know I am getting the right DEB package :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn’t that your system’s version of Harfbuzz is too old, it’s that the Desktop Dimmer binary provided in the package embeds a version of Harfbuzz that’s too old.

I’m not sure how the dependency is pulled in, but hopefully rebuilding from source would use a newer version.

Comment: The project seems to have multiple issues. Even building from source fails. Are there other such screen overlay apps to dim the desktop for Ubuntu? I don't want to touch the hardware brightness since it causes PWM flickreing.

Comment: No that I’m aware of (but I see you’ve asked a separate question, thanks).

Comment: That was done on purpose :)